# authenticating asp.net core application from another port

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication, single-page-application

I have an asp.net core MVC application and an SPA front-end. my asp.net core MVC application works on  44747 port, and my SPA application works on port 3000.

I can see my authentication cookies are shared among these domains after signing in from MVC, and it's using cors.

when my SPA front-end tries post to an action, it simply returns a 302 redirect to login page.

How can I make my MVC accept the cookies from SPA and keep it authenticated (At least for development mode)

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: You can read this article, maybe it will help you. Also it's better to provide your code to better solve the problem. https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/2_interactive_aspnetcore.html